# Is there a way that a variable in PL/SQL can be equal to a SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

this is the code:

```sql
DECLARE
v1 C_table.cout%TYPE;
v2 C_table.km%TYPE;
BEGIN
v2 := Select km from C_table where v1 = 1;
END;
```

When I type this, it gives me a bunch of errors(caused by the `:= SELECT...`). Is there a way to make *`v2`* equal to the result returned by the select?

Comment: The Oracle documentation is comprehensive, free and online. You can find answers to straightforward syntax questions like this by looking at its examples. I admit in this case the relevant section would not be immediately obvious to a beginner but [it's this part of the PL/SQL Reference, Processing Query Result Sets](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/static.htm#GUID-E6BCE8B1-71AA-459F-845F-2C34541A534D).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `INTO` (and set the value of `v1` and compare it to the column):

```sql
DECLARE
  v1 C_table.cout%TYPE := 1;
  v2 C_table.km%TYPE;
BEGIN
  Select km INTO v2 from C_table where cout = v1;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( v2 );
END;
/
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE C_table ( cout, km ) AS
SELECT 1, 42 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> 42
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=83f9ad416dedc91370d76dbc9955a0ac)*